# Finding all the solutions of the system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I'm struggling with the following problem:

Consider the system of equations of three unknowns $Ax=b$, for which we know that:

a) $A≠0$.

b) $(1, 2, 2)$ and $(0, 1, 1)$ are solutions,

c) $(0, a, b)$ is a solution if and only if $a=b=1$.

I'm asked to find all the solutions of the system.

---

The issue is that I'm not sure how to use c). Particularly the fact that no other solution of the form $(0, a, b)$ exists.

Also, the teacher uses $b$ first as a vector, and then as a scalar. My guess is that when $b$ is used as a vector it is meant to be $(b, b, b)$.

I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

---

I'm including the original problem here by petition of a user, it is however in Catalan.

[image]

I admit the teacher isn't clear in what is wanted, I believe he means us to solve

$$A\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} b \\ b \\ b \end{pmatrix}$$

such that for some fixed value $b=b_1$ we have that $(1, 2, 2)$ is a solution (similarly, for some fixed value $b=b_2$, we have that $(0,1,1)$ is a solution, in which case we know by c) that $b_2=1$), and such that $ay+bz=b$ if and only if $a=b=1$.

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be a column vector? If so, then it'd usually be written as $x$ rather than $X$ (to avoid interpreting it as a matrix).

Comment: "three unkowns"? you mean $X\in\mathbb{R}^3$? or $A, X, b$ are all unknowns?

Comment: Also, do you have the original statement of the problem? That may help clarify what the intent is.

Comment: @mrsamy I believe the teacher means that the system of equations represented by $A$ has three unknowns. In other words, that the vector $x$ has dimension $=3$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, I added it, although it is not in English, which is why I included a translation at first as opposed to a picture.

Comment: @Leo: then the $b$ on the right hand side should be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But you also use it as a scalar when you say $a=b=1$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I believe $X$ is a column vector, my teacher still writes it in caps which is odd.

Comment: @Leo: do you have  a link to your book?

Comment: @mrsamy Yes it is weird. I think when it is used as a vector it is meant to represent $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ b \\ b \end{pmatrix}$? I really see no other thing the teacher could have meant by this.

Comment: @mrsamy It's a set of excercises, not a book, and I'm not sure how to share a .pdf here.

Comment: @Leo: do you have a  link to the file? It is much easier to do the problem seeing the context around it.

Comment: @mrsamy Yes, but I believe it won't work without being logged in to the University's website. https://campusvirtual.ub.edu/pluginfile.php/3083974/mod_resource/content/0/Sistemes.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118535/discussion-between-mrsamy-and-leo).

Comment: In case $b$ denotes a real number, $A$ is doomed to be a $3$-dimensional row vector.

Answer (score 1):

(I only presume that a system whose coefficient matrix is $A$ has solutions satisfying the conditions (a), (b), and (c) regarding that "$AX=b$"-thing for a typo otherwise the problem would be senseless.)

Clearly the solution set's dimension is neither zero nor three.

Assuming the solution set has dimension $1$ (and assuming that $A$ has three columns, of course) the solution is a straight line given by
$$x=w+s\cdot u$$
with a suitable replacement-vector $w$ and a direction-vector $u$, where $u$ is an element of the kernel of $A$.  Now a candidate for $u$ is easily found: as $(1,2,2)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are solutions their difference $u=(1,1,1)$ is an element of the kernel.

For the replacement vector simply choose $w=(0,1,1)$; the solutions are given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}
+s\begin{pmatrix}
1\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which may also be written as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
+r\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\-1\\-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

As $u$ and $w$ are not parallel the only solution who's first coordinate is zero is just $w$ as
$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\a\\b
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}$$
has only solution $s=0$.

In case the solution set's dimensions equals two, rref has the form
$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & \alpha & \beta & \gamma
\end{array}$$
hence the solutions are given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
+r\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\-1\\0
\end{pmatrix}
+s\begin{pmatrix}
\beta\\0\\-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
As $(0,1,1)$ must be a solution we conclude that in this case $r=s=-1$ and hence $\gamma=\alpha+\beta$.

As $(1,2,2)$ must be a solution we conclude that in this case $r=s=-2$ and from here $\alpha+\beta=-1$, that is $\beta=-1-\alpha$.
Finally the solutions are given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\-1\\0
\end{pmatrix}+r\begin{pmatrix}-1-\alpha\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

As obviously
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\-1\\0
\end{pmatrix}\text{ and} \begin{pmatrix}-1-\alpha\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
are linearly independent, $(0,a,b)$ is a solution iff $a=b=1$.